# Is it possible to print results on beat?

Tags: python

I'm trying to print a list of sentences to the rhythm of a song, and have the python file play the song as well. Is there a way to print to a certain bpm, or have the file recognize the bpm of the song?

Comment: You can always call `time.sleep(0.3)` (or similar) between calls to `print`; that will get you the outputs at a timing you specify.  As for figuring out the bpm of the song (to know what values to pass in to the `time.sleep()` call), that is a much harder problem; I think you're on your own there.

Answer (score 1):

The [Echo Nest Remix](http://echonest.github.io/remix/python.html) library might be able to help you here

Use this library to retrieve the BPM of the file and then use `time.sleep()` with a value in seconds that is the result of whatever interval you want.

Hope this helps - happy coding!